# Reading row count from Cursor

Tags: android, sql, database, cursor

How do I get the row count of a Cursor without using `moveToFirst()`?

(Is it possible to do .getCount() without doing .moveToFirst() ???)

**Logcat**

> 11-29 13:37:40.370: E/SQLiteLog(8459): (11) database corruption at
>   line 62665 of [00bb9c9ce4]
>
> 11-29 13:37:40.370: E/SQLiteLog(8459): (11) statement aborts at 44:
>   [select pos, definition, sample FROM word INNER JOIN sense ON
>   word.wordid = sense.wordid INNER JOIN synset ON sense.synsetid =
>   synset.synsetid LEFT JOIN sample ON sample.synsetid =  syn

**Code**

```
try {

    if (sqldb2 == null || !sqldb2.isOpen()) {
        dbobj2 = new SqLiteConection(context,
        "/mnt/sdcard/sk2.db");
        sqldb2 = dbobj2.openDB2();
    }
    // if(sqldb2!=null){
        cursor_n = sqldb2.rawQuery(NOUN, null);
        cursor_n.moveToFirst();
        if (cursor_n.getCount() > 0) {
            if (cursor_n != null) {
                if (cursor_n.moveToFirst()) {
                    do {
                        String strin = cursor_n
                        .getString(cursor_n
                        .getColumnIndex("definition"));
                        d_noun_List.add(strin);
                    } while (cursor_n.moveToNext());
                    searchData_DTO.setD_nounList(d_noun_List);

                }

            }
            cursor_n.close();
            }else {
            break;
            // record not found
        }        

    } catch (Exception e) {

Log.d("in Exception", "reason" + e);}
```

Comment: Till now i have tried with 
1.cursor_n.moveToFirst()
2.cursor_n.getCount() > 0
3.cursor_n.getColumnCount() > 0
4.cursor_n!=null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done by myself by doing the backup of the db

Answer (score 0):

Use .getCount function to get the row count

```
Cursor.getCount()
```

Comment: It works fine in case there is record but throws exception when there is no rows exits.

Comment: Write this code under an if condition,where it will check if the row exists else nothing.

Comment: i have done the same way it goes to if and then throws in Exception(1901): reason android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabaseCorruptException: database disk image is malformed (code 11)

Answer (score 0):

To get row count you can use:

```
cursor_n.cursor.getCount();
```